# RoR and Filemaker Where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, filemaker

Not sure if this is possible, but I am wondering if I can compare two fields  in a `where` As I am trying to avoid `if` statements in this case.

For example:

```
Article.where(clidlive: '*', "#{mod_date} > "#{releae_date})
```

- `mod_date` is a date field in filemaker
- `releae_date` is a date field
  in filemaker.

I'd really appreciate if you could direct me to the right path, or even this is possible.

Thanks, 
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

Longer answer: Rails has no knowledge of filemaker or its records until you point Rails to FM. You can use this gem to do so: https://github.com/ginjo/rfm

Once you parse the data you could store it in SQL to use ActiveRecord query methods in the style you listed above:

`Article.where.not(clidlive: nil).where("mod_date > ?", release_date)`

You could also create a calculation on the filemaker side and just query that field. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try with a calculation field in FM and see how it performs.

Comment: @RKurti - To follow up, doing a lot of  calculations on the FM side can be very slow, so ensure what you are doing isn't performance critical!